# What is the best way to do CI/CD with AWS CDK (python) using GitLab CI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK (with Python) for a containerized application that runs on Fargate. I would like to run `cdk deploy` in a GitLab CI process and pass the git tag as an environment variable that replaces the container running in Fargate. I am currently doing something similar with CloudFormation (`aws cloudformation update-stack ...`). Is anyone else doing CI/CD with AWS CDK in this way? Is there a better way to do it?

Also, what should I use for my base image for this job? I was thinking that I can either start with a python container and install node or vice versa. Or maybe there is prebuilt container somewhere that I haven't been able to find yet.

Here is start that seems to be working well:

```
CDK:
  image: python:3.8
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apt-get -qq update && apt-get -y install nodejs npm
    - node -v
    - npm i -g aws-cdk
    - cd awscdk
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - cdk diff
    - cdk deploy --require-approval never
```

Edit 2020-05-04:

CDK can build docker images during `cdk deploy`, but it needs access to docker. If you don't need docker, the above CI job definition should be fine. Here's the current CI job I'm using:

```
cdk deploy:
  image: docker:19.03.1
  services:
    - docker:19.03.5-dind
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache python3
    - python3 -V
    - pip3 -V
    - apk add nodejs-current npm
    - node -v
    - npm i -g aws-cdk
    - cd awscdk
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - cdk bootstrap aws://$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID/$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    - cdk deploy --require-approval never
```

The `cdk bootstrap` is needed because I am using assets in my cdk code:

```
        self.backend_task.add_container(
            "DjangoBackend",
            image=ecs.AssetImage(
                "../backend",
                file="scripts/prod/Dockerfile",
                target="production",
            ),
            logging=ecs.LogDrivers.aws_logs(stream_prefix="Backend"),
            environment=environment_variables,
            command=["/start_prod.sh"],
        )
```

Here's more information on `cdk bootstrap`: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/design/cdk-bootstrap.md

Comment: You can build your own python-nodejs-awscdk image. Push it publicly (hub.docker.com) and use it as a Gitlab runner base. Have another weekly Gitlab CI update the image with the latest stable python/nodejs/awscdk versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you definitely have to use CDK deploy inside the CI/CD pipeline if you have lambda or ECS assets, otherwise, you could run CDK synth and pass the resulting Cloudformation to AWS Code Deploy. That means a lot of your CI/CD will be spent deploying which might drain your free tier build minutes or just means you pay more (AWS Code Deploy is free)

I do something similar with Golang in CircleCi. I use the Go base image and install nodejs and cdk. I use this base image to build all my go binaries, the vuejs frontend and compile cdk typescript and deploy it.

```
FROM golang:1.13

RUN go get -u -d github.com/magefile/mage
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/magefile/mage
RUN go run bootstrap.go

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm i -g aws-cdk@1.36.x
RUN npm i -g typescript
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt update && apt install yarn
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, what should I use for my base image for this job? I was thinking that I can either start with a python container and install node or vice versa. Or maybe there is prebuilt container somewhere that I haven't been able to find yet.

For anyone looking for how to implement CI/CD with AWS CDK Python in 2022, here's a tested solution:

- Use `python:3.10.8` as the base image in your CI/CD
  (or any image with Debian 11)
- Install Node.js 16 from [NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions): `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs`
- Install [aws-cdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cdk): `npm i -g aws-cdk`

You can add the two latter steps as inline scripts in your CI/CD pipeline so you do not need to build your own Docker image.

Here's a full example for Bitbucket Pipelines:

```yaml
image: python:3.10.8

run-tests: &run-tests
  step:
    name: Run tests
    script:
      # Node 16
      - curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs
      - npm i -g aws-cdk
      - pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
      - pytest

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    "**":
      - <<: *run-tests
  branches:
    master:
      - <<: *run-tests
```

Note that the above instructions do not install Docker engine. In Bitbucket Pipelines, Docker can be used simply by adding

```yaml
services:
  - docker
```

in the [configuration file](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/).

Answer (score 0):

If `cdk deploy` is giving you the error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:12422
    home = path.join((os.userInfo().homedir ?? os.homedir()).trim(), ".cdk");
```

then the `node` version is out of date. This can be fixed by updating the docker image which also requires pip3:

```
cdk deploy:
  image: docker:20.10.21
  services:
    - docker:20.10.21-dind
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache python3
    - python3 -V
    - apk add py3-pip
    - pip3 -V
```